# Is there a way so that I can access all the items in the browser history or atleast top item of history

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, browser-history, react-router-dom

I have a scenario in which I have to take some action on submission of a form.

I come to this particular form from two routes. Lets say /first-route and /second-route

Now my aim is simple, If I come from /first-route I have to go back to /first-route on submission of the form. But if I am coming from /second-route or any other I have to go to /third-route.

Is there a way to access the last item in react-router history object so that I can conditionally do this routing.

The function `history.goBack()` takes me back to the last route but what I want is to check this route first before going back

If the route is say /first-route I want to do `history.push('/first-route')`. In other cases I have to do `history.push('/third-route')`.

Also for more context I have a two independent react apps between which this communication has to take place.

I have two apps which are embedded in a third application. I want to keep the parent app independent of this communication.

Answer (score 0):

Properties
Each history object has the following properties:

`history.length - The number of entries in the history stack`
`history.location - The current location (see below)`
`history.action - The current navigation action (see below)`

Additionally, createMemoryHistory provides history.index and history.entries properties that let you inspect the history stack.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/history